# Notepad++ folding code

Tags: notepad++, delimiter, folding

I've created a UDL in Notepad++, but there's 1 thing I cannot get to work.
I'd like to be able to fold code from a ":JumpLine:" to the next:

```
- :MaxCheck:    //Pure safety work, so it will not override existing scripts
  Add("%LastScriptID%","50");

// Comment
- :AddSCR:
  Print("Creating ID keeper for missing ScriptTypes...");
```

So the code should should be folded from :MaxCheck: until :AddSCR: or the first new line above it, so I can keep comments too, leaving only this visible:

```
+ :MaxCheck:

// Comment
- :AddSCR:
  Print("Creating ID keeper for missing ScriptTypes...");
```

I would also be able to still highlight it as a delimiter so the user easily notices it.
So far it would only fold everything from the point I click and below it, without it being a delimiter. Which means I cannot use it both as a delimiter and folder?
Can this be done?

Comment: Consider another text editor, SynWrite, which can have lexer of much more flexibility. Just read the lexer tutorials in Synw Readme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folding you are expecting is not supported in Notepad++ UDL's. Please check this [answer on similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145476/notepad-udl-problems-with-folding-start-and-end/22983767#22983767).